# Testing Chrome app with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-app

I have some Selenium WebDriver Java tests running fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, now I want to make it work on a Chromebook app. I guess there's no way to run it directly on a Chromebook, so I am trying to run it in Chrome. I installed the extension, I also have its id, but how can I launch it and run tests against it?

I found out how to start Chrome with an extension loaded, but cannot find any info on how to run actually tests on it.

Just to be clear, I am not talking about starting Chrome with a loaded extension, I am talking about running automated tests on a Chrome app? One example, Pocket app: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket/mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk

Comment: What does the extension do?

Comment: It's a web page converted to a Chrome app

Comment: I'd love to mark this question as NOT duplicated...

Comment: Then you'll need to very carefully explain what you're trying to do and why the existing answer doesn't do it.  Just saying "it's not a duplicate" isn't very useful, especially when you've not given us anything to show they may be different.

Comment: I added this to the initial question: "Just to be clear, I am not talking about starting Chrome with a loaded extension, I am talking about running automated tests on a Chrome app (or extension)" A web site is converted to Chrome App. How do you run tests against it? unfortunately I cannot provide the app, BUT I have a similar example. How do you run tests against POCKET app? Here it is: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket/mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk

Comment: @vicusbass Whether you've got an app or extension does not matter. In both cases there is no out-of-the-box support for running tests. So you have to add "test" functionality to (a special build of) your app, and run it somehow. In that sense, it is a duplicate of [Running a chrome extension from Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825371/running-a-chrome-extension-from-selenium-webdriver). Since your question is specifically about v2 apps and not extensions, I've re-opened your question.

Comment: The method suggested (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825371/running-a-chrome-extension-from-selenium-webdriver/25446621) does not work for this case.
I tried these steps, but I am getting a warning in Chrome settings.

>There were warnings when trying to install this extension: >'web_accessible_resources' is only allowed for extensions, hosted >apps, and legacy packaged >apps, but this is a packaged app.

When launching the extension (app) I get: chrome-extension://invalid/ in browser

Any idea?