# How to get the number of ads blocked on a page, using Watir / AdBlockPlus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium-webdriver, watir, adblock

I'm running a headless browser in ruby using [Watir::Browser](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver). If I use a firefox profile and add the adblock plus extension, is there a way to display in my app the number of ads blocked on a page?

Comment: Try to see if this question helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825371/running-a-chrome-extension-from-selenium-webdriver or check out their API - https://adblockplus.org/jsdoc/adblockplus/symbols/AdblockPlus.html#constructor