# Java Selenium. How to use chrome with addons?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

We have addon to chrome to use some featuren on our test server. How can i integrate our addon to crome driver if its possible?

I'm using chrome driver like this

```
public void Before(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "J:\\Java_Testing\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions. Chrome extensions can be either packed or unpacked. Packed extensions are a single file with a .crx extension. Unpacked extensions are a directory containing the extension, including a manifest.json file.

To pack an unpacked extension, use the Pack button in chrome://extensions or use Chrome: "chrome.exe --pack-extension=C:\path\to\unpacked\extension --pack-extension-key=C:\myext.pem". See the extensions docs for other ways to do this that are more automation friendly. To unpack a packed extension, just unzip the file (you may need to rename the file from .crx to .zip for your zip utility to recognize it). Installing extensions via ChromeDriver

Packed (.crx file)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Unpacked (directory)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=/path/to/extension");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: perfect! plugin added! but... it turns off when page loaded, can i activate it from driver while on page?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222412/load-chrome-extension-using-selenium

Comment: i dont see the answer to my second question there(

Comment: I m out of office Dmitry .. You can post it as an second question on stackoverflow .. I can look into tomorrow .. Sorry for inconvenience