# C# Selenium how to interact with chrome extension

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have successfully loaded my chrome profile with selenium that has pre-installed extensions.

The extension in question is called [Private Internet Access](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/private-internet-access/jplnlifepflhkbkgonidnobkakhmpnmh?hl=en), but i have tried others and cannot communicate with them

I am trying to figure out how i can open the extension below and enter username&password and click login button. I have tried finding the elements in by id and class but it doesnt find them. Can someone point me down the right line for this. Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more information about the extension you want to interact with. It is a little difficult to tell from the screenshot, although the screenshot is helpful.

Comment: done, its private internet access extension,

Comment: The name of the extension is good, but is there a link with more information?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/private-internet-access/jplnlifepflhkbkgonidnobkakhmpnmh?hl=en

Comment: I'm not finding much about this either. There is a similar Python question: [How do I interact with a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55646658/3092298), which is unanswered, but has lots of good links. There is also [How to test Chrome extensions in Selenium](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-chrome-extensions-in-selenium) on BrowserStack. Sorry I cannot help more.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had the ability to try this - however I've done a lot of work with Selenium and I've created my own chrome extension.

That extension popup in the top right actually a different web page. You won't be able to interact with it due to how it's presented, but you can navigate to it.

Try this:

1. Open up your extension, right click anywhere and select `Inspect`. This will open up devtools for the popup.

[image: inspect on extensions]

2. In devtools, go to the `console` and type `document.url`. This will give you the URL of that popup page. (you'll also see it at the top of the title bar)
   [image: devtools popup]

That gibberish-looking bit in the middle doesn't change - it's your chrome extension identifier. From when I created my extension and 18 months worth of updates (including migrating from chrome extension manifest v2 to v3) it has not changed for me.  I think you'll be safe to use it.

3. Go to that URL to make sure it works. In my case it's `chrome-extension://ojhcleddagaoaplflbafhpekcciikdop/popup.html`
   [image]

You'll notice you'll lose some of the page styling compared to the popup. When you design the popup you give it fixed dimensions - when you open it as a normal webpage, you lose that and everything gets stretched.

4. Finally - for your automation - put that `chrome-extension:\\` url as the first step in your selenium script and do your sign in. Then, carry on with the rest of your test.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunatly for my particular use case opening in a seperate tab will not work. An event on the main page cause this popup to appear and at this point I would like to enter usernamer and password, sorry i didnt make that clear in original post

Comment: @Frank: I don't think what you want to do is possible. I linked to more information that basically agrees with this answer. Maybe navigate to the extension login page first, and then proceed to the system under test?