# How do I solve an Arkose FunCaptcha on LinkedIn using 2Captcha when the CAPTCHA is embedded within an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, captcha

I am attempting to automate solving CAPTCHAs when logging into LinkedIn via 2Captcha in my Python/Selenium/Google Chrome script.

To do so, per the [answer of a previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76909582/unable-to-find-data-sitekey-attribute-in-hcaptcha-on-indeed-selenium-automation), I load the CRX file for the 2Captcha Chrome Extension when instantiating my webdriver, and enabling autosolve for all CAPTCHAs.

However, for LinkedIn, the extension is unable to detect the CAPTCHA because it is inside an `<iframe></iframe>` element of the webpage. To bypass, this, I added the following to my Python script to detect and solve the CAPTCHA:

This script below still does not detect and properly solve FunCaptchas. May I know what I can do to detect and solve LinkedIn CAPTCHAs that are inside an `<iframe></iframe>`? For reference, an image of what this CAPTCHA and a snippet of LinkedIn's code (below mine) are attached.

My Python Code:

```
try:
    solver = TwoCaptcha('<API_KEY>')
    captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
                                    "//input[@name='captchaSiteKey']")
    captcha_sitekey = captcha.get_attribute('value')
    iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
    iframe_source = iframe.get_attribute('src')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    
    print(f'IFRAME Source: {iframe_source}')
    print(f'CAPTCHA SiteKey: {captcha_sitekey}')

    time.sleep(60)
    result = solver.funcaptcha(sitekey=captcha_sitekey, 
                                url=iframe_source)
    
    for key in result:
        print(f'{key}: {result[key]}')
    
    print('We found and solved a CAPTCHA.')
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
except Exception as e:
    print(f'We could not solve the CAPTCHA because {str(e)}, '
          f'{traceback.print_exc}')
```

(I did not write it in the block of code above, but I'm importing the `traceback`, `2captcha-python`, and `selenium` modules.

LinkedIn's HTML on the CAPTCHA page:

```
<iframe class="" id="captcha-internal" src="./Security Verification _ LinkedIn_files/funCaptchaInternal.html"
    frameborder="0" role="presentation" title="Captcha Challenge" height="290" width="302"></iframe>
<form method="post" class="hidden" id="captcha-challenge" action="https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/challenge/verify">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:6505936439590984220"><input type="hidden" name="captchaSiteKey"
        value="3117BF26-4762-4F5A-8ED9-A85E69209A46"><input type="hidden" name="challengeId"
        value="AQFvUtZMWireaAAAAYvTP-Lq8KvlyrCr7xCgZlth6uf4UoJSq7UrP1-4bNpriHtPql8mOpZipQF3qa1vNAec2TT9aef2xMVB0Q"><input
        type="hidden" name="language" value="en-US"><input type="hidden" name="displayTime"
        value="AgFP_RD3wseHwQAAAYvTP-L3CpYje8Fh1rkGPsUfvp7WGYv0NvYEqR_gAaCDCew"><input type="hidden"
        name="challengeType" value="AgFU-zncyoLVdAAAAYvTP-L66dj0drF5826EpedJld3sNEQ0b8diSPFWlBU"><input type="hidden"
        name="challengeSource" value="AgGudd74ELMaKQAAAYvTP-L9K5-uGH1mPDpZy1yUGcdWEbCi3jtReJS_a-ufgicE"><input
        type="hidden" name="requestSubmissionId"
        value="AgF0RnGQ2BTi9QAAAYvTP-MA56TcJxjPSm3P71dof2-LrpBUMFM96V4_2m0pYDnLWnYMTPz9HIZ-TuCX35YFJgKBYom7WXc3eTGfrQ"><input
        type="hidden" name="captchaUserResponseToken" value=""><input type="hidden" name="challengeData"
        value="AgFlYfn-cheGuwAAAYvTP-LySUtucNcd5hW7d3PzwesMuCW97DRwpH_XItP5Ynt4E_dL4mZC18kF-5UGtjZ_l25oIZXIrhpW_qjH84--g65ZGktWQJloVkNrMiY3BrOTB1PuqhvwDnYhJj3o-jM54s5Ap1-0U7zDiU6lgAkA92Ez01S2-PBr15R44ZrVoFQPuRhOsUKQdSjREh4sPw6zjyx-9EYXEgPwnwWbCNjT8GpYr1GkobR0bQsa0RLjgkSOQ7KxV4iTVoYYHgt7UFssZQykI0PdVypaYVft3OoZTewLoz2Tg6GcIU58TItd4ulUP8gGj4NpKsQiMtqxf9mxs1hxkKtoOt29ZJ3RPa0Ge9z0bUYzjKChJNdORYHzSJcmnBPY4az1z3mw4hh7F0wbzZouuAb6yCwGtX_6sEnuaewCHBSaEbv-VwmNgDGk8-k_z-seh_2z2Q-s5gPanbEPBjhhseq9OBweFlXmSRf6h9KTlcizSGgBx7Yz9YBirkob2ukkxuU9yhmZ9911cUVMJ-ZaQU0jNOZW9PEX4ZLinEAWi5ei3X2bXfIc3lVhQ89RN-6t9G9uRFbOKOcrisiPt2MgDTBVni0QLkPcDOQyAahyxiTwJg8ksp3cPi16xZd4zr2VHiIT0Dm8CuI4GPImNdfMKjqZWuPjS7KC0_CtHvXa03cwfQAXSYGzDIX7obdutQ2XWT3JyXF4sz3o03bPIn2p0f7Aejd2yI6AH5krsacMqaVrSfLjSBq4xRBjLLg"><input
        type="hidden" name="pageInstance"
        value="urn:li:page:d_checkpoint_ch_captchaV2Challenge;KXxlvP5+SpygwcfBd+7rDg=="><input type="hidden"
        name="challengeDetails"
        value="AgFwKVDCcGn56wAAAYvTP-L1wL8sH9K8QYfqk4ydRmaR9VTdhiElPBT1pJ9zSFYaYZU7F6ulGXRJjDXGNCiOU_57wWr4ae19I_rc9qVKYlm5ggO43Yr8Q_AJX6TOv5s_fqbcAEakFbLgVvIu46NVK_TI1lwtIXay"><input
        type="hidden" name="failureRedirectUri"
        value="AgFg3MLPYMreRAAAAYvTP-MC_VIvK3O8g0pYH_FBHDR5q1XBY77au_DHDHrV1c78mXMKKhjrXIC-8vKyXQZuC7ashO7hSP0qRmwORfm-ECf1Tjuisx6n_Q"><input
        type="hidden" name="signInLink" value="/checkpoint/lg/login?trk=homepage-basic_sign-in-submit"><input
        type="hidden" name="joinNowLink" value="/signup/cold-join?source=homepage-basic_sign-in-submit"><input
        type="hidden" name="_s" value="CONSUMER_LOGIN">
</form>
```

[image: LinkedIn CAPTCHA image.]

Comment: What do you do after you receive a response from 2captcha? How do you pass it to linkedin?

Comment: I attempted passing the response to an input tag in the <iframe> but that didn't work. I use proxies now to avoid CAPTCHAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just looking at your code I think you need to switch to the iframe bevor you search for the captcha like this:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
iframe_source = iframe.get_attribute('src')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe) 
captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
                                "//input[@name='captchaSiteKey']")
captcha_sitekey = captcha.get_attribute('value')
```

Because without switching to the iframe, selenium can't find elements inside it.

If that doesn't help: Where does your script fail? What is the output of the print statements?

Comment: Thanks for this r000bin. I'm going to run this shortly and give the bounty if it works.

Comment: @r000bin I have got token throught 2captcha API calling, but I am not sure where should I use this token to bypass captcha in linkedin.
On the 2captcha document, they said that I have to use this value for id with "fc-token", and submit or click some button.
But I am not sure about this at linkedin.
So I hope you help me, what should I do after getting token. I uploaded some images: 
https://imgtr.ee/image/Ibd9zG
https://imgtr.ee/image/IbdRle
https://imgtr.ee/image/IbdMv7
https://imgtr.ee/image/IbdVTx