# How to access country restricted proxy website through urllib.request

Tags: python, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver, http-proxy, urllib3

I am trying to build a selenium scraper that rotate its IP address after every n request, for this i need to access a free proxy website in order to construct a list of IP:port addresses, the problem is that i am executing my code from a country that bans proxy websites, thus the code can't access the proxy website and  is returning me this error:
 raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Here is my part of code that try to access https://www.sslproxies.org/ website:

```
ua = UserAgent() # From here we generate a random user agent
proxies = [] # Will contain proxies [ip, port]
proxies_req = Request('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
proxies_req.add_header('User-Agent', ua.random)
proxies_doc = urlopen(proxies_req).read().decode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(proxies_doc, 'html.parser')
proxies_table = soup.find(id='proxylisttable')
```

The error is occuring from the fifth line :

```
proxies_doc = urlopen(proxies_req).read().decode('utf8')
```

any suggestions?

Comment: ...if the site is blocked you're either going to have to find a way around the block (and accept the risks of doing that) or just accept that it won't work. Are you able to load that site using other tools, e.g. a regular web browser?

Comment: with regular browser (chrome), i can open it manually using Ultrasurf chrome extension

Comment: what you mean by around the block?

Comment: Ultrasurf also uses a proxy web server. Do you know why Ultrasurf's proxy works?

Comment: @bunbun because it is an extension not a website( the country blocks the websites not extenstions), am thinking of using the chrome browser with the as it is with the ultrasurf extension, i have just to close the browser  : browser.quit()  and open it again to get the IP changed, what you think?

Comment: yep you can write a bash script to open and close the browser i guess. Not sure if selenium allows loading of plug-ins in chrome. If you still want to go the selenium way I can help you find out if thats possible, or if you need help with bash scripting

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222412/load-chrome-extension-using-selenium`

Comment: Why use the bash script since the selenium command : browser.quit() does the job?

Comment: ah i thought you wanted to open chrome with the ultrasurf extension manually, mb. yeah seems like you already know about selenium extension loading so go ahead with that