# Relaxing Chrome's CSP while running tests (webdriver) (Content-Security-policy)

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, content-security-policy

I'm trying to relax Chrome's CSP while running a test using proctractor (webdriver, chromedriver).

So the solution can be either

1. a flag like "--disable-csp" which dose not exist according to my search results.
2. a setting for webdriver/protractor to do so.

I could not find any solution but to setup a proxy that filters the header.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

currently there are no native option but you can disable CSP using extension.

Step:

1. Download extension [Disable Content-Security-Policy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden)
2. Save it as `.zip`, because it need modification to enable "disable CSP" at start
3. extract the file or if using Winrar double click file `background.js` to edit
4. change `var isCSPDisabled = false;` to `true`
5. save change.

code

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path/to/disableCSP.zip') # or disableCSP.xpi
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: There is no code that can do it ? But how did the extension do it then ? :)

Comment: @Matt Chrome extensions work on higher level -- within browser, not within the browser tab page.

Answer (score 2):

I update @ewwink's answer

1. Go to the website of the extension developer [Disable CSP github](https://github.com/PhilGrayson/chrome-csp-disable)
2. Download the extension code in zip format
3. Unzip and modify the background.js file with:

```
    var isCSPDisabled = function (tabId) {
        return true; // disabledTabIds.includes(tabId);
    };
```

4. In Chrome go to:
   ... -> Tools -> Extensions -> Active the Developer mode -> Pack extension ...
   Choose the modified folder as the root directory -> Leave the field: private key file blank -> This will create a .crx file next to the extension folder, and a private key as if it were the developer
5. Use the generated crx file like this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_extension("/path/to/chrome-csp-disable-master.crx")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

source: [Load chrome extension using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222412/load-chrome-extension-using-selenium)