# Relaxing Microsoft Edge CSP while running tests (webdriver) (Content-Security-policy)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I'm trying to relax Microsoft Edge CSP while running a test using proctractor (webdriver, chromedriver).

So the solution can be either

1. flag like "--disable-csp" which dose not exist according to my search results.
2. setting for webdriver/protractor to do so.
3. load an extension that dose that ( Like in chrome
   [Relaxing Chrome's CSP while running tests (webdriver) (Content-Security-policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304222/relaxing-chromes-csp-while-running-tests-webdriver-content-security-policy))
   I could not find any solution but to setup a proxy that filters the header.

any ideas?

Comment: Do you control the site or just the browser?  You could maybe set a cookie that turns off CSP when detected?

Comment: @StephenR , In my case I do not control the website, but it's a great way to achieve the same results in case you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on the best approach by taking the [same approach for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304222/relaxing-chromes-csp-while-running-tests-webdriver-content-security-policy), using the same answer from the previous question, and just converting the Chrome extension to a Microsoft-Edge one.

1. Follow the linked question to the point you got.
2. Convert the Chrome extension to an Edge extension using [this tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions)
3. Use the **extensionPath** option to load the extension.