# Selenium's Chrome webdriver stuck while login

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, adfs

I am trying to test a page using Selenium and Chrome Webdriver (using Java). In Windows there is no authentication because it uses the domain login to enter. But in Linux (I plan to run in Linux this test) I got an ADFS login prompt saying please login to adfs.xxx.com to proceed. I tried embed user and password (simple authentication) in to the URL but nothing changed.

Also in debug mode the line after the navigation command never gets executed so I think this might not be a browser modal. If I enter manually user and password the debug goes on and reach the line I'd marked.

Comment: I ran 'xprop WM_CLASS' in order to know who owns the adfs login window and the answer was 'WM_CLASS(STRING) = "google-chrome", "Google-chrome"'. So, if this belongs to the browser why user:password@url isn't working ?

Comment: Maybe there is a different between 'belongs to' and 'is controled by'. Anyway it depends on username and password values too. I have 2 different pages with different credentials. Simple values without special characters are ok, but passwords like "...,,,fooBAR123" just don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my company, one solution I have come up with is to use a user that will log in to my application and this user is an ADFS account. if you are in the same situation ask your sysadmin to provide you with that user name or granted your user name to become an ADFS account.

another approach is to create chrome extension thanks to [Load chrome extension using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222412/load-chrome-extension-using-selenium)
its an excellent alternative solution for chrome browser