# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot process extension #1 from unknown error: CRX verification failed: 3

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Given Robot framework with Selenium is ready to execute tests in Chrome
And it worked so long time
When I execute the tests in Robot framework with Jenkins
now I receive an error
"02:05:44 WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot process extension #1 02:05:44 from unknown error: CRX verification failed: 3"

Is it possible the upgraded Chrome and driver is not able to use older plugins?
What should I do to solve this problem?
Upgrade the plugin?
Upgrade the driver (might be older driver is there)?

Answer (score 7):

The new chrome does not support `CRX2` format of extensions. 
You need to repackage your old extension or download the latest versions from the developers site.

How to repack extension:

1. Download extension locally. (you can use online crx-downloader, for example https://crx-downloader.com/).
2. Check version of your extension with site https://crx-checker.appspot.com/ that it is `CRX2` format
3. Unpack extension as `.zip` archive to a folder
4. Open chrome at `extensions://extensions/` and press button `Pack Extension`.
5. Profit! Use repacked extension on your tests!

**Official info of Chrome M78 (October 2019)**

```
The ExtensionAllowInsecureUpdates policy will be ignored.
Chrome will no longer install or update to extensions packaged with CRX2 format.
All extensions must be packaged with CRX3 format.
```

The error you are seeing "CRX verification failed: 3" is used when the format is incorrect. Specifically this error means that the header of the crx could not be parsed successfully. We will be improving this message in version 80.

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/mlNyuTZ2U-A

Comment: The link for chrome should be chrome://settings/ and make sure you select developer mode to get the Pack Extension option

Comment: #4 on you answer, Chrome throwing "Manifest file is missing or unreadable"

Comment: When clicking the source link, I get the message "You don't have permission to access this content"