# selenium - Chromedriver- extension - Python / crx to crx3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, crx

since google updated chrome  , i can not add crx extension to the chromedriver in selenium , it throws an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: CRX verification failed to parse extension header. Chrome supports only CRX3 format. Does the extension need to be updated?
```

does anyone know how to convert crx extension to crx3 ? i searched everywhere in Internet but no solution . Thanks alot

my search results without success > 
[WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot process extension #1 from unknown error: CRX verification failed: 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762418/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-cannot-process-extension-1-from-unk)

Answer (score 0):

-Go to chrome://extensions/
 -At the top right, turn on Developer mode.
 -Click Load unpacked.

Should be able to do this with selenium.

Alternatively, get an older version of chromedriver?
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads