# Running Chrome from PortableApps with Selenium WebDriver fails

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, portability

I've got C# Selenium project and want to run portable Chrome downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/GoogleChromePortable64_83.0.4103.106_online.paf.exe/download).

My `chromeOptions` are:

```
chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = Path.GetFullPath("C:\", "tests.browsers", "windows", "chrome", "GoogleChromePortable.exe"));
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--enable-logging");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--v=1");
chromeOptions.AddExtension(Path.Combine("path", "to", "kontur-plugin.crx"));
```

But when I run the test, Chrome opens and shows this:

[image: screenshot]

(notifications say "Failed to login %EXTENSIONNAME%, click to load it once again)

`chrome_debug.log` contains no errors.

What am I doing wrong? How can I figure out what is the problem with?

Answer (score 1):

this might help you - [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762418/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-cannot-process-extension-1-from-unk/58899807#58899807)

also, your CRX file should add as a file, not just the path.