# Python : chrome webdriver setting the path to store extension files

Tags: python, webdriver

I'm using webdriver for my testing, right now when I install the chrome extension the extension files are getting stored in temp folder, is there any way I can define the path where it should be stored.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Vetrimarann, Thanks for posting in stack overflow , Question Looks Clear, It would be great if users know version of chrome driver your using.

Comment: Hi Dilip the version I'm using is 83.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Selenium module to help store the extension files. Here's a link that can help:

[Load chrome extension using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222412/load-chrome-extension-using-selenium)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No Gavin, Thanks Gavin but this didnt help, I'm trying to change the extension download path, right now extension files are getting stored in temp folder.