# Selenium proxies handling

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Does anybody know how to handle this kind of proxies with selenium: ro.smartproxy.com:13125:user-opz817058:H2Azfjpc76x17058 ??

I've tried the code from link bellow, the first answer, but the chrome window auto close.

[how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python)

```html
PROXY_HOST = 'ro.smartproxy.com'  # rotating proxy or host
PROXY_PORT = 13721 # port
PROXY_USER = 'opz817058' # username
PROXY_PASS = 'H2Azfjpc76x17058' # password
```

Comment: As far as I know, there’s no built-in way to pass along proxy server credentials in Selenium. [This](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-proxy-in-selenium_) post might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [osfresia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16399561/osfresia), there is no built-in way for proxy authentication in selenium. I have already tried selenium-wire, but this also didn't work as expected.

However, you can download an extension and pass your proxy along with your credentials over to the extension. Check out [this](https://digital.ai/catalyst-blog/how-to-use-browser-extensions-with-selenium-testing) post or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222412/load-chrome-extension-using-selenium) from stackoverflow.