# Python selenium executing add-on

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, add-on

```
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : DESIRE_SAVE_PATH}
chop.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chop.add_extension(FILE_LOCATION)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath, chrome_options = chop)
```

I've already created the .crx file to make chrome load up the add-on when it launches. Next, I want to make it click the add-on button at the top right corner to make it execute. I was able to do it by using pyautogui to make it manually click it. However, I'd rather not have the program clicking all over the place. Is there a better way? If anyone could point me to the right direction, that'd be great.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you provide `HTML` code for `Add` button?

Comment: Or you want just to run your extension in browser? What is `add-on` button?

Comment: Like, let's say adblock's addon as an example. Perhaps I mean the extension?

Comment: So `add-on` button it is an extension icon on browser extensions panel near `Bookmark this page`, `Save to pocket`, `Home` icons, right?

Comment: Correct. Is it called an extension?

Comment: Yeap. Your extension opens in the same browser window as web-application or as GUI?

Comment: I'm using the webdriver to load up a chrome with the chromedriver. The chrome that is loaded up has the extension in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `Chrome-extension` in your browser, you don't need to click it's icon from extensions panel, you can run it manually at first and when extension page loaded save it's `URL` to variable. It should looks like

```
extension_url = 'chrome-extension://just_sequence_of_symbols/addon_name.html'
```

and then you can run it automatically:

```
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : DESIRE_SAVE_PATH}
chop.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chop.add_extension(FILE_LOCATION)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath, chrome_options = chop)
driver.get(extension_url)
```

Comment: I'm not quite following. Let's use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invert-page-colors/hjhdnhiofjddcapmffbllcpaodjmdphn as an example. I want the sequence to be like, load a url, click the add-on

Comment: oh, you mean extension without web-interface? just enabled/disabled options?

Comment: Yes, I want to start simple for now. So it's going to be a simple enable/disable. Links to examples would helpful too if it would take too long to explain. I'm not sure where to google it, since I don't really know where to start.

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done with`selenium-webdriver` as extension button it's not a web-element... You can check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825371/running-a-chrome-extension-from-selenium-webdriver . Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.